# python text hockey game, issue adding items to inventory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to do a text game for school and having issues adding the items to inventory , I have the moving between rooms working but the inventory is what's getting me now. I just keep getting errors no matter how I set up the get items, I have issues. Is there an easy way to add this functionality that I am missing?

```
# Game Description
# The main character is an ice hockey goalie for the local home team. 
# Their cities rival is playing them tonight and the opposing team’s goalie broke in to the locker room
# and hid the home teams goalie equipment all over the building to try and rattle him causing him to lose time warming up. 
# This includes his helmet, chest armor, blocker, glove, and each leg pad.  
# Time is clicking off and the home team goalie needs to find his stuff so he can get dressed and warm up.


rooms = {
    'Front Lobby': {'East': 'Ice Rink', 'Item': 'Glove'},
    'Ice Rink': {'North': 'Away Locker Room', 'West': 'Front Lobby', 'East': 'Mens Locker Room', 'South': 'Lounge', 'Item': 'Helmet'},
    'Away Locker Room': {'East': 'Pro Shop', 'South': 'Ice Rink'},
    'Pro Shop': {'West': 'Away Locker Room', 'Item': 'Villian'},
    'Mens Locker Room': {'West': 'Ice Rink', 'Item': 'Leg Pad 2'},
    'Lounge': {'West': 'Womens Locker Room', 'East': 'Skate Rentals', 'North': 'Ice Rink', 'Item': 'Blocker'},
    'Womens Locker Room': {'East': 'Lounge', 'Item': 'Leg Pad 1'},
    'Skate Rentals': {'West': 'Lounge', 'Item': 'Chest Armor'}
}
gameOn = True
inventory = []

#moves player from room to room
def move(player, direction):
    global rooms
    current_room = player 

    # check if there is a room in the specified direction
    if direction in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][direction]

    # error handling
    else:
        print("There is nothing in that direction!")
        return player # Returning the same room if nothing Exists in the direction

    # return the player state
    return current_room # Indent Error

#displays rules at start of game 
def showRules():

    print("- Collect 6 items to win the game, or have to get clowned by the other goalie.\n" "Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West.\n" "Add to Inventory: get 'item name'. Once all items collected type: ‘Finish’")


def main():
    showRules()
    player = "Front Lobby" 

    while gameOn:

        current_room = player

        # output
        print(f"\nYou are in the {current_room}")
        print('Inventory: ',  inventory)

        # Goalie got you
        if player == 'Pro Shop':
            print('You make more excuses than saves. GAME OVER')
            break

        # input validation and parsing
        print("----------------")
        player_move = input("Enter your move:\n") 

        # invalid move syntax
        if 'go' in player_move or 'Finish' in player_move:
                
    
            # split string 
            
            action = player_move.split(' ')
            print(action)        # move 
            if action[0] == 'go':
                player = move(player, action[1]) # Assigning the value to player 
                                                 
            elif action == 'Finish':
                if len(inventory) == 6:
                    print('Awesome! Now get on the ice! You Win.')
                else:
                    print('Keep collecting items')
    
            # invalid action
            else:
                print("Invalid command!")
        
        elif 'get' in player_move:
            action = player_move.split(' ')
            getItem(current_room, action[1])
            
        else:
            print('Invalid Command')
            continue


def getItem(player, item):
    current_room = player
    if item in rooms[current_room]:
        inventory.append(item)
        print(inventory)
    
    

main()
```

updated the code 11:05 EST

Comment: There are at least some syntax errors in your code like at line 80 `if action[1] == ` (should be followed by something). Then could you be more specific about what errors you are getting ?

Comment: Also, I don't see where you are trying to add something to `inventory`, is it present in your code ?

Comment: I updated the post , i copied and pasted the wrong thing , sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your getItem function more like this:

```py
def getItem(current_room, item):
    if item == rooms[current_room]["Item"]:
        inventory.append(item)
        print(inventory)
```

Explanation:
in you original expression `item in rooms[current_room]`, rooms[current_room] points to a dictionary, so the `x in dict` expression will check if `x` is part of the key of that dictionary.
But if I understand well, you are only interested by the "Item" part of that dict, and you have to make the comparison with the value and not with the key.

Answer (score 0):

I ran it through my Python compiler and came up with a syntax error. You missed the second condition and action in your block in one of the last if/elif/else blocks in `main()`. I don't know much but I think the code might be this:

```
elif 'get' in player_move:
            action = player_move.split(' ')
            if action[1] == <second condition here>:  #The second condition was missed here
                <action> #The action was missed here
```

IDK about the code you want there.

I'm not completely sure but I think there is something wrong with the `move()` function. Try the other answer, adding this snippet to `getItem()`:

```
    if item == rooms[current_room]["Item"]:
        inventory.append(item)
        print(inventory)
```

If that doesn't work, then send me an email: shivernscorch@gmail.com and we can take it from there.